# copying a property from child array into main object

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of products like

```
[ 
{name:'Test1', id:1, prices: [ 20,25,30 ] },
{name:'Test2', id:2, prices: [ 21,26,31 ] },
...
]
```

each `product` has an array of `prices` depending of the product `sizes`.
I want to automatically create a new property in each object, which get the first price from corresponding array and writes in the `product` object

like

```
{name:'Test1', id:1, prices: [ 20,25,30 ], pr: 20 }
```

Comment: Cool. What have you tried so far? Because that's a pretty easy thing to do, and we'll be happy to help you make the code that you wrote and you think should do the trick but doesn't, work. However, for us to do so, you need to *have* some code, first.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const a = [ 
    {name:'Test1', id:1, prices: [ 20,25,30 ] },
    {name:'Test2', id:2, prices: [ 21,26,31 ] },
];

const newArr = a.map(item => {
    item.pr = item.prices[0]
    return item;
});


console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it helps!

```
var array = [ 
    {name:'Test1', id:1, prices: [ 20,25,30 ] },
    {name:'Test2', id:2, prices: [ 21,26,31 ] }
];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].pr = array[i].prices[0];
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use map. Assuming your array is called objects. Use sort if your prices are not in order. Or you can loop through and find the lowest value, if your worried about performance.

```
objects = objects.map((obj) => {
    obj.pr = obj.prices.sort()[0];
    return obj;
})
```

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tardycorgi9917/7d417wdL/